# How to solve "org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"" selenium error

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, dropdown

I'm going to get the default selected value of  the below dropdown

[image]

[image]

I wrote below code to do it.

```
Select selectyear = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("year")));
WebElement year = selectyear.getFirstSelectedOption();
String selectedoption = year.getText();
```

But this throws the following error

org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"

How can I fix this? same code is working perfectly for dropdowns that don't have "value" attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only explanation is there is another element with id `year`, the `input` tag.

Put this code before `Select selectyear = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("year")));`:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("year"));
        for (WebElement element: elements) {
            System.out.println("Tag: " + element.getTagName());
            System.out.println("Text: " + element.getText());
            System.out.println("Location: " + element.getLocation());
        }
```

Solution is relative xpath for the select: `select[@id='year']`

Comment: yes there is a radio button with same id. I will try relative path and see